# create single bytes instance from sequence of memoryview

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, memory-efficient

**tl;dr** Given a `Sequence` of `memoryview`, how can I create a single `bytes` instance *without* creating intermediate `bytes` instances?

The naive approach creates many intermediary instances of `bytes`

```
def create_bytes(seq_mv: Sequence[memoryview]) -> bytes:
    data = bytes()
    for mv in seq_mv:
        data = data + bytes(mv)
    return data
```

The function `create_bytes` creates `len(seq_mv) + 1` instances of `bytes` during execution. That is inefficient.
I want `create_bytes` to create *one* new `bytes` instance during execution.

Comment: Did you try `bytes().join(seq_mv)`?

Comment: Indeed, [`join` is here in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.join), too. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bytes` as you got it, is an imutable object.

As *the* Tim Peters put in the comments, you can let Python create a single instance with all parts joined together with a single call to `bytes().join(seq_mv)`.

If you need to perform any other operation on your data that would involve changing it in the way, you could be using the mutable `bytearray` instead- which not only gives you flexibility to change your object, but have all the advantages of mutable sequences.

You can then make a single conversion to `bytes` at the end of your function if the users of your function can't deal straight with a a bytearray (but maybe you can just return it directly):

```py
def create_bytes(seq_mv: Sequence[memoryview]) -> bytes:
    data = bytearray()
    for mv in seq_mv:
        data.extend(mv)
    return bytes(data)
```

Or simply:

```py
from functools import reduce

data = reduce(lambda data, mv: data.extend(mv), seq_mv, bytearray())
```

Comment: Ah, good use of `reduce`! This is a nice _extended_ answer ;-) . Indeed, [`join` here in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.join). Thanks!